How to properly handle Android Jetpack Compose Insets with IME
I’ve been trying to solve an inset with problem Jetpack Compose and I’m completely stuck. I’m having a hard time understanding what’s wrong with my implementation, as this was all very straightforward using XML.
I've tried following the guides, a few tutorials and scouring through other questions here but I'm not being able to find the right solution, each has a different problem so I'm clearly missing something.
What I currently have enabled:

Added adjustResize in the manifest.

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">


Added setDecorFitsSystemWindows

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false
    
    checkAppSettings() // Just checks some data store settings.
    
    setContent {
       val viewState = viewModel.viewState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    
       MyTheme(darkTheme = viewState.value.uiMode.isDarkTheme()) {
            MainScreen()
       }
    }
}


Added imePadding() and systemBarsPadding() to my main Scaffold. I also change the visibility of the bottom bar to fix the issue of the bottom bar being pushed alongside the content.

Note: I've also tried different combinations that I've lost count, including removing the main Scaffold and replacing it with a Column that has the navHost with weight(1f) and the bottom bar below it, but still no dice.
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .imePadding()
            .systemBarsPadding(),
        bottomBar = {
            if (!WindowInsets.isImeVisible) BottomNavigationBar(navController)
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->
        NavigationHost(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues),
            navController = navController
        )
    }
}

To expand further, my structure is as follows from the MainScreen onwards:
    \- MainScaffold \
        \- MainNavHost \
            \- SelectedBottomNavItemNavHost \
                \- SelectBottomNavItemScaffold

And to add a bit more details to the SelectBottomNavItemScaffold, this is what it looks like on pretty much every screen:
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        // This uses Material TopAppBar internally
        CustomTopAppBar(
            topAppBarVariation = TopAppBarVariation.Title(title = stringResource(id = label)),
            showIcons = state.shouldDisplayEditFeedIcon(),
            actions = {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable(
                        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                        indication = ripple(bounded = false),
                        onClick = { navController.navigateTo(FeedNavigationItem.FeedEdit) }
                    ),
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_edit),
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.edit)
                )
            }
        )
    }
) { paddingValues ->
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(paddingValues)
    ) {
        // Page content goes here, now.
    }
}

The specific problem:
The actual problem can be seen in these two videos I've shared below:



Do not hide bottom bar
Add a WindowInsets.isImeVisible check to the bottom bar




https://imgur.com/HkLysj7
https://imgur.com/SY3xhz6



In the first approach we do not hide anything. The bottom bar scrolls with the keyboard and looks  fine. However, there's some jitter when scrolling the content up if you focus a text view at the bottom of the screen. If I select a text view at the top of the screen, no problem happens.
On the second approach, we hide the bottom bar, but this causes a white space to appear (sometimes bigger initially and animates jitterly to a smaller size). I'm not sure if it's related to the caret, as there's a square that appears that matches the white space but it doesn't have any name or selection available in the layout inspector, as can be seen here.
What can I try next?

Well, upon reading some unrelated things from SO for another problem after two days of debugging, I stumbled upon a reference to the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" being used in the <activity> tag instead of the <application> tag.
Moving from the application tag to the activity tag fixed all my issues 
Hopefully this helps someone in the future to not do the same newbie mistake as me!
